# How to assign specified height and width for com.android.camera.action.CROP's clipping box

Tags: android

I just find those value's for com.android.camera.action.CROP.Can I specified `height` and `width` for `com.android.camera.action.CROP`?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 480);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 480);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", false); // no face detection
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to please check out the link as follows:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

And if you want's to change the height and width then change the value in the following code and check out the result:

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 480);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 480);
```

And review the aspect ratio